# Error al Añadir Llaves Foraneas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando una base de datos bastante simple pero al agregar las llaves foráneas por algún motivo me salta este error (Cree las tablas en el orden que aparecen)

`CREATE TABLE
    t_vehiculo(
        id_vehiculo INT PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
        id_modelo INT,
        propietario VARCHAR(100)
    );
CREATE TABLE
    t_marca(
        id_marca INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        descripcion_marca VARCHAR(100)
    );
CREATE TABLE
    t_modelo (
        id_modelo INT PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
        id_marca INT,
        descripcion VARCHAR(100),
        FOREIGN key (id_modelo) REFERENCES t_vehiculo (id_modelo),
        FOREIGN key (id_marca) REFERENCES t_marca(id_marca)
    );`

Así es como debe quedar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una llave foránea, apunta a una Llave, `id_modelo` no es una llave; es requisito que exista un índice sobre la columna referenciada.

Answer (score 2):

La clave foránea `id_modelo` se define en `t_vehiculo` y tú la tienes definida en la propia `t_modelo`.

Es la misma filosofía que con la marca y el modelo, que el `id_marca` es clave foránea en `t_modelo` y no en `t_marca`

```
CREATE TABLE
    t_vehiculo(
        id_vehiculo INT PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
        id_modelo INT,
        propietario VARCHAR(100),
        FOREIGN key (id_modelo) REFERENCES t_modelo (id_modelo)
    );
CREATE TABLE
    t_marca(
        id_marca INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        descripcion_marca VARCHAR(100)
    );
CREATE TABLE
    t_modelo (
        id_modelo INT PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
        id_marca INT,
        descripcion VARCHAR(100),
        FOREIGN key (id_marca) REFERENCES t_marca(id_marca)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues la estructura está bien. Por lo que veo entoendo que solo debes poner la tabla t_modelo antes que la de t_marca:

```
CREATE TABLE
t_vehiculo(
    id_vehiculo INT PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_modelo INT,
    propietario VARCHAR(100)
);


CREATE TABLE
t_modelo (
    id_modelo INT PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_marca INT,
    descripcion VARCHAR(100),
    FOREIGN key (id_modelo) REFERENCES t_vehiculo (id_modelo),
    
);

CREATE TABLE
t_marca(
    id_marca INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    descripcion_marca VARCHAR(100),
    FOREIGN key (id_marca) REFERENCES t_modelo(id_marca)
);
```

Comment: No, realmente aparece el mismo error al tratar de crear la tabla 't_modelo'

Comment: Pues que extraño, no sé como te exigen que lo hagas para decirte que no está en orden correcto

Comment: Nop, pues así como aparece en la imagen, se supone que debo crear las tablas con sus relaciones

Comment: Faltaba una coma antes del segundo foreign, por si igual no lo habias visto. De todos modos, deberías pdoer tener algo mas de info sobre donde está el fallo, o en base a tus apuntes u otros ejercicios..

Comment: Si si la vi, la vdd se me hace muy raro pq he hecho este tipo de ejercicios miles de veces y nunca me había sucedido

Comment: Pues me da que el ejercicio está mal hecho o no sé que se nos pasa jaaj

Comment: Bueno pues ahí miro como soluciono, graciass

Comment: Siento no poder ayudarte más. Cuidate pa 